# How to perform supervised training of a deep neural network when the target label has only 0 and 1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a Deep Neural Network (DNN) with labeled data. The labels are encoded in such a way that it only contains values `0` and `1`. The shape of the encoded label is `5 x 5 x 232`. About `95%`  of values in the label is `0`and rests are `1`. Currently, I am using `binary_crossentroy` loss function to train the network.

What is the best technique to train the DNN in such a scenario? Is the choice of `binary_crossentroy`
as the loss function is appropriate in this case? Any suggestion to improve the performance of the model.

Answer (score 1):

You can try MSE loss. If you want to stick to binary cross-entropy (used in binary classification), consider using label smoothing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Currently, I am not familiar with the term 'label smoothing'. I try to learn about it and include it my training process.

Comment: 95% of 0 and 5% 1 means that your dataset is highly imbalanced, isn't it?

Comment: @DhanushkaSandaruwan The said problem is not a classification problem. The target is a 3D array and not one-hot encoded. The position of 0 and 1 follow a different pattern.

Comment: If so, you had better provide more details to have a better idea. However, wish your success. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use 2 other alternative loss functions instead of Binary cross-entropy.They are

1. Hinge Loss

An alternative to cross-entropy for binary classification problems is the hinge loss function, primarily developed for use with Support Vector Machine (SVM) models.
It is intended for use with binary classification where the target values are in the set {-1, 1}.

2. Squared Hinge Loss

For more Detail on loss function with examples.[click here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-choose-loss-functions-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/)

Hope helpful, happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

1. `binary_crossentroy` as loss is fine
2. Don't use accuracy as your metrics, because model will just predict every thing as label `0` and will still get 95% accuracy. Instead use F1 score (or precision or recall)
3. Use Weighted loss: I.e penalize class 1 heavily if they are wrong  as compared to class 0.
4. Instead of class weights you can also use methods like oversampling form the minority class. (Techniques like SMOTE)

## How to calculate class weight

- You can use `sklearn.utils.class_weight` to calculate weight from your labels. Check this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have some more doubts. The target of the model is a 3D array and are not one-hot encoded. Also "class_weight" is not working with the 3D array in Keras.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios where you have highly imbalanced data, I would suggest going with Random Forest with up-Sampling. This approach will up-sample the minority class and hence improve the model accuracy.